# Azure | Form Recognizer pre selection of documents?

Tags: azure, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Does Form Recognizer has the ablity to pre-select/pre-diffrentiate documents before they get worked over by the Form Recognizer recognition tool?

E.g. It would be able to diffrentiate between bills or notes and would only use the recognition tool for bills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers had suggested, you could implement your own classifier.  You could call the model, and exam the confidence score of return value, if it's too low, then it's not the document you want to process.

If you want to build 2 models, one for bills, one for notes,  each model extract different sets of key/values,  then Form Recognize team is working on a feature to find the most appropriate form for you, please stay tuned.

thanks

-xin (from MSFT Form Recognize Team)

Comment: Thanks Xin! That would be interesting to clearly mention in your reply that you are part of Form Recognizer teams at Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

Azure Form recognizer  is a cognitive service that uses machine learning technology to identify and extract text, key/value pairs and table data from form documents, whether they are PNG, JPEG, TIFF  or PDF.

With Form recognizer, You cannot find the type of the document or differentiate document. You need to train any type of form before the extraction of data.

For the purpose of segregation, you have to use some other service/tool. For example, Azure Computer Vision service can be used to find the type of image.

Comment: Not Azure Computer Vision... Azure "Custom" Vision can do classification with a specific training

Comment: For images - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/#features

It can also find the type of document as image format.

Comment: What do you mean by type of document? We are not talking about file type (jpg, png, etc) but type in terms of content (ex: image of a bill vs image of notes). I'm okay to say that Computer Vision could be useful here only in 1 way: text reading, if the split between types can be made based on text in the document. In other case, it's a classification problem that Computer Vision can not process

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not a feature from Form Recognizer.

You can implement your own classifier (for images documents) using Custom Vision for example